# Java - Accept different keys from user to do different tasks, terminate when user clicks "X"

Tags: java, recursion, input, constructor, key

I'm still a newbie to Java so if this question sounds dumb, please enlighten me. Any suggestion is appreciated.

I'm thinking of some way to implement a program which allows user to input a key from the keyboard to do different tasks. The thing is, the program should be able to continue **until** the user clicks a specific key, let's say, "X".

This is part of the class PizzaDemo I'm working on and part of the getPizzas() method which performs the above task:

```
    public class PizzaDemo {
        private PizzaOrder list;
        public PizzaDemo(){
            list = new PizzaOrder();
        }

        public static void getPizzas(){
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("To add a new Ham & Cheese pizza, press H.");
            System.out.println("To add a new Pepperoni pizza, press P.");
            System.out.println("To add a new Tropical pizza, press T.");
            System.out.println("To exit, press X");
            String input = sc.next();

            while(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("H") && !input.equalsIgnoreCase("P") && !input.equalsIgnoreCase("T") && !input.equalsIgnoreCase("X")){
                System.out.println("Invalid key. Enter again: ");
                input = sc.next();
            }

            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("H")){
                System.out.println("Enter the size of the pizza: ");
                String size = sc.next();
                System.out.println("Enter the number of ham toppings: ");
                int n1 = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter the number of cheese toppings: ");
                int n2 = sc.nextInt();
                Topping[] top = {createTopping("ham", n1), createTopping("cheese", n2)};
                Pizza p = createHamCheese(size, top);
                PizzaDemo demo = new PizzaDemo();
                demo.list.setPizza(p);
                getPizzas();
            }

            // the rest of the code is omitted

        }
    }
```

The problem is, I can't seem to find any way to use the constructor in such a way that the previously added element can still be kept even though the recursion (in the if block) is called. Anyone has some suggestion for me? The constructor is used for initializing a new pizza order, and it's a part of the program so I cannot omit it.

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use recursion for this. You could end up with a stack overflow, no pun intended. Use a loop.

```
public static void getPizzas(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;
        do{
            //put code in here
        } while(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("X");
    }
```

Comment: okay then then maybe calling the constructor outside the loop would help?

Comment: yeah, I completely missed the fact that your constructor was in there.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to provide an overloaded constructor that takes the List of Pizzas as an arg.